# C compiling progam that uses OpenCV library with Makefile

Tags: c, opencv, makefile, linker-errors

Hi I have project in `CLion` written in C language that uses **OpenCV library**. 
I have configured it with `CMake` and it compiles and runs very well. But I also have my own `Makefile` in directory, now I would like to add to this Makefile **support for OpenCV library**.

Here are lines I have added to this Makefile:

```
# libraries
# OpenCV
OPENCV_CFLAGS = `pkg-config —-cflags opencv` 
OPENCV_LIBS = `pkg-config —-libs opencv`
```

and then:

```
$(TARGET): main.c $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_SOURCE_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) main.c $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_SOURCE_FILES) $(UNIT_TESTS_LIBRARY) $(OPENCV_LIBS) $(OPENCV_CFLAGS)
```

While I am doing `make -f make.txt` it doesn't compile and the problem is:

```
fatal error: 'cv.h' file not found
#include <cv.h>
```

I also try to use this:

```
# include headers 
CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include/opencv
```

But despite cv.g has been found there is another error:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/core/core_c.h' file not found
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
```

No I changed this to:

```
# include headers 
CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include
```

and also `#include<cv.h>` to `#include<opencv/cv.h>` no there no error message about not found header files, but some linking problems like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the problem I make this in Makefile:

```
# include headers
# CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include

# libraries
# OpenCV
OPENCV_LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

and than while compiling target:

```
$(TARGET): main.c $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_SOURCE_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) main.c $(LIBRARY) $(TEST_SOURCE_FILES) $(UNIT_TESTS_LIBRARY) $(OPENCV_LIBS)
```